# Multiple ssh key for the same gitlab host

Tags: ssh, gitlab, ssh-keys

I'm having two gitlab.com accounts and since GitLab does not allow me to use the same ssh key, I have to generate two ssh keys.

I'm trying to config the ssh, here is my config:

```
Host company
    HostName gitlab.com
    User vunh
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Host private
    Hostname gitlab.com
    User hoangvu271297
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/private
```

Both accounts are logged in to the same domain **gitlab.com**.

Previously, I did not config anything because I only use the **id_rsa**.
Until now the **id_rsa** still works fine but I can not find a way out to clone the project using the **private** one.
I tried many configs on the Internet but no one works.

Is there any way to deal with this situation? I knew it is configurable if there are two different hosts such as **gitlab.com** and **work.gitlab.com**

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#use-different-accounts-on-a-single-gitlab-instance) covers this scenario.

You should setup your ssh config using two different `Host` configurations for each user. Say, `user_1.gitlab.com` and `user_2.gitlab.com`. You can use whatever value you want here, these are just examples.

```
# User1 Account Identity
Host user_1.gitlab.com
  Hostname gitlab.com
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/example_ssh_key1

# User2 Account Identity
Host user_2.gitlab.com
  Hostname gitlab.com
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/example_ssh_key2
```

You then use these `Host` keys when setting up your git repos.

For example, to clone using `user_1` account:

```
git clone git@user_1.gitlab.com:gitlab-org/gitlab.git
```

Note that you should NOT provide your username as the `User` configuration in your SSH config. The username you use to connect to GitLab over SSH is ***always*** `git`. The **identity file** (ssh key), not ssh user, determines the GitLab user account.

Comment: It does not work

Comment: @NguyenHoangVu can you update your question with your updated config, the commands you are running, and the errors/unexpected behavior you are seeing?

Comment: Thanks @sytech ! It works perfectly !
The one thing I didnt know that 'Host' must be special. After I replace mine for one in the copied "Clone with SSH" string in project it starts working )